# How like '#if DEBUG' and '#endif' remove content between two marks

Tags: c#, regex

How like '#if DEBUG' and '#endif' remove content between two marks

E.g:
Below SQL string expect like '#if DEBUG' and '#endif' to remove string between `/**if DEBUG**/` and `/**endif**/`

```
select
    id
    ,name
    /**if DEBUG**/
    ,test1
    ,test2
    /**endif**/
from table
where sDate >= '2021-01-01'
    /**if DEBUG**/
    and test1 = '123456'
    /**endif**/
```

expected result :

```
select
    id
    ,name
from table
where sDate >= '2021-01-01'
```

### What I've tried

I tried use regex

1. `(\/\*\*if\sDEBUG\*\*\/)(?<content>)(\/\*\*endif\*\*\/)`
2. `(\/\*\*if\sDEBUG\*\*\/)|(\/\/[\w\s\']*)|(\/\*\*endif\*\*\/)`

to get string but not work, my code:

```
void Main()
{
    var input = @"
select 
    id
    ,name
    /**if DEBUG**/
    ,test1
    ,test2
    /**endif**/
from table
where sDate >= '2021-01-01'
    /**if DEBUG**/
    and test1 = '123456'
    /**endif**/            
            ";
    var matchs = Regex.Matches(input,@"(\/\*\*if\sDEBUG\*\*\/)(?<content>)(\/\*\*endif\*\*\/)")
        .Select(m=>new {Key = m.Groups["content"].Value,Value=m.Groups["content"].Value})
    ;
    foreach (var m in matchs)
    {
        input.Replace(m.Value,"");
    }
    Console.WriteLine(input);   
}
```

Comment: IMHO define 2 string constants surrounded by `#if DEBUG` / `#else` / `#endif` ?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman yes, thanks, I fixed it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use [`Regex.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-5.0#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_Text_RegularExpressions_RegexOptions_System_TimeSpan_) directly? Note that you can use `.*?` to capture the text between the debug markers as long as you use [`RegexOptions.Singleline`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions?view=net-5.0) to make `.` match a newline:

```cs
void Main()
{
    var input = @"
select 
    id
    ,name
    /**if DEBUG**/
    ,test1
    ,test2
    /**endif**/
from table
where sDate >= '2021-01-01'
    /**if DEBUG**/
    and test1 = '123456'
    /**endif**/            
            ";
    input = Regex.Replace(input, @"/\*\*if\sDEBUG\*\*/.*?/\*\*endif\*\*/", "", RegexOptions.Singleline);
    Console.WriteLine(input);   
}
```